# How to set html template in emailMessage of amplify cognito using cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

How can we pass html content to emailMessage using CLI which is ByDefault used in amplify cognito auth ?

> emailVerificationMessage

I want to set html content to "emailVerificationMessage" using CLI but I'm not able to set it so anyone have idea how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Is this fine now ? I have edited question content